# didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called in included nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I've a class say clsBase, is the base class of all other classes. And I've a Title class which contains TitleBar at the top. In TitleBar nib there's a menu button clicking on it, it shows a `UITableView`. This `UITableView` is in the TitleBar nib file.

What I wanted is to include this TitleBar nib file to my all other nib files. Suppose I've a UserProfile nib which extends clsBase class and in clsBase I've a method say `setTitleView`

```
- (void)setTitleView:(UIView*)view
{
    TitleBar = [[TitleView alloc]initWithNibName:@"TitleView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [TitleBar.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    TitleBar.Target = self;
    TitleBar.Action = @selector(onButtonClicked:);

    [view addSubview:TitleBar.view];
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` of my UserProfile class I call parent (clsBase) class method `setTitleView` so that it include TitleBar.

What my problem is I've override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the TitleBar class. And from my UserProfile nib when I click a cell `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is not being called.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Comment: @Rushi Yes, I've set DataSource as well as Delegate, Even data is being shown in the TableView but didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not being called

Comment: could you include the code? I'm not quite following what you are trying to do (and why).

Comment: @StefanFisk I've a TitleBar which is common in all view. So I include TitleBar in all views using setTItleView method (given in the question). In TitleBar class I've a UITableView whose didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is not being called... let me know which code do you want to observe?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, but figured it out by just setting the allow selection to true for the table view.

```
[YourTableView setAllowsSelection:TRUE];
```